# ASUS nat'd behind cable modem or bridge mode which is better security?

Tags: networking

I have setup VPN for my home network but want to switch to bridge mode for the cable modem, i own the modem, are there any concerns security wise for doing this?  I know nat'ing puts a list a little but of obfuscation out there but was wanting everyone's thoughts.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.  We are not a forum, so a question attempting to collect "everyone's thoughts", is out of scope here at Superuser and every StackExchange community.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you somehow have a *chunk* of IPs (in which case you wouldn't be using consumer hardware) you're going to *need* to use NAT.

Looking at my own asus router, there are two choices: Using it as a full router, or as a standalone AP. Newer models apparently may also do mesh.

[image]

There's no bridged option. You can use AP mode if your cable modem is *also* a router. I tend to prefer a standalone router, simply because of flexibility, as well as most combo devices kinda not being very good.

Depending on your VPN, you can either run it on a different range, or bridge it into your current one. The latter's great if you need access to all your systems remotely. If it's on a different range, it's more for connecting to a single system.

Comment: I didn't explain it well.  I want to put my cable modem in bridge mode therefore putting my asus directly on the internet and not nat'd behind my cable modem.

Comment: Oh. Double Nat is vile, so that seems generally sensible

Comment: Modem combos are a bain to my existence. In my mind the engineers of these devices are i.t super villains.. +1